# How to filter a collection in Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have three documents in a collection, like so:

```
[
  {"_id": "101", parts: ["a", "b"]},
  {"_id": "102", parts: ["a", "c"]},
  {"_id": "103", parts: ["a", "z"]},
]
```

what is the query I have to write so that if I input `["a","b","c"]`
(i.e. all items in `parts` field value in each doc should be present in  `["a","b","c"]`) will output:

```
[
  {"_id": "101", parts: ["a", "b"]},
  {"_id": "102", parts: ["a", "c"]}
]
```

is this even possible? any idea?

Comment: You can try an aggregation query using [Set Expression Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-expression-operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution may not be the best but it works. The idea is finding all documents that has no items in `parts` outside the input array. It can be done with combination of [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/), [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

```
db.collection.find({
  parts: {
    $not: {
      "$elemMatch": {
        $nin: ["a", "b", "c"]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ch71ny0D74b)

Comment: why do you think this is not the best solution? is this solution good if there are lots of docs in the collection? @Cuong Le Ngoc

Comment: if you have time can you improve my answer posted on this page, thanks a ton.

Comment: It's because i dont't know all mongodb operators so I think it may have a less complicate solution @blueseal

Comment: if you have some spare time, would you like to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63916390/how-to-filter-a-collection-based-on-each-array-item-in-a-doc-field-in-mongodb @Cuong Le Ngoc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @prasad_. I have tried to come up with a solution which is similar to what I wanted. I have used [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) here.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      diff: {
        $setDifference: [
          "$parts",
          [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
          ]
        ]
      },
      document: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "diff": {
        $eq: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "diff": 0
    }
  },
  
])
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "101",
    "document": {
      "_id": "101",
      "parts": [
        "a",
        "b"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "102",
    "document": {
      "_id": "102",
      "parts": [
        "a",
        "c"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lieGT5-YvoY)