# How to filter a collection based on each array item in a doc field in Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a collection, like so:

```
[
{ "_id": "101",  parts: [1.2, 2] },
{ "_id": "102",  parts: [2, 3.5] },
{ "_id": "103",  parts: [4.1, 10] }
]
```

What is the query I need to write so that each item in the array `parts` is greater than equal to the item with the same array index in an input array `[1, 5]`?

output would be:

```
[
{ "_id": "103",  parts: [4.1, 10] } // 4.1 >= 1 and 10 >= 5
]
```

is this possible? any idea?

Comment: The `parts` array and the _input_ array have same number of elements?

Comment: yes, same number of elements @prasad_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot notation and run following query for your example:

```
{"parts.0":{"$gte":1},"parts.1":{"$gte":5}}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hUaQu1N0RTz)

or use below JS code to build something more generic:

```js
let input = [1,5];
let query = Object.fromEntries(input.map((val, i) => ([ "parts." + i, { $gte: val } ])));

console.log(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the input array before query then you can create query object from it first then pass this object to the query:

```
let query = input.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
  acc['parts.' + index] = { $gt: cur };
  return acc;
}, {});
// [1, 5] will create {"parts.0": {$gt: 1},"parts.1": {$gt: 5}}
db.collection.find(query)...
```