# filter Mongo DB collection

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to filter a collection using a particular field called (`type`) in the collection. The field type has six different values (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`) for example. I want to get the collection for type `A`, `B`, `C`. I tried the below code and is not working

```
collection.find(and(eq("type", A), eq("type", B), eq("type", C))
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63896791/how-to-filter-a-collection-in-mongodb

Comment: you can use $and or $in operator  for the task: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: [`collection.find({"type": {"$in": ["A", "B", "C"]}})`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UIgVMA4_N_F "Click me!")?

Comment: You want to find collection(s) that has documents with `type` A, B, C or find document(s) with `type` A, B, C within a collection? That's different things and for latter you can just use the suggestions from other comments.